# what is difference between echo and return

Tags: php

I have created my own plugin in which i have created admin menu at left side on dashboard and i also ising shortcode in it. For example

```
function forms_options(){
    $content='';
    $content.='hello';
    echo $content;
}
add_shortcode('sample','forms_options');**
```

When i use "echo" it show output only in plugin. and on wordpress page show "updation failed".

while i use return,

```
function forms_options(){
    $content='';
    $content.='hello';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('sample','forms_options');**
```

It shows output on wordpress page without any error and on plugin page(which shows right side on dashboard) shows nothing.

what is reason behind and how i can solve it someone help me please.

Comment: `Echo` sends the specified output to the browser, `return` returns it to the calling line.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is just a php function to write some text to the screen. `return` sends the value from a function back to the calling function. The reason you see your text when you use 'echo' is due to the fact that nothing is being sent "back to Wordpress" to be printed into the rendered HTML. You are sidestepping it using echo.

You need to look at your php error log and see what the errors are (or use xdebug and a good IDE and just step through the code. This can be very helpful for figuring out software that has an unknown error, and how you should attempt to fix it.   It may be something as simple as returning an object instead of a string but no one can guess what is going wrong.

Comment: could you give me example , may i understand deeply.please

Comment: like how can i show output on pages aswell as on plugin menu

Answer (score -1):

In WordPress, you may want to only some value generated by `do_shortcode()`.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

It's a better practice to return the `html` instead of displaying it.